# jQuery selector not html tag or class or id

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, handle

I was wondering if the following is possible.

- When you want to assign a handle to an id its used as $("#idhere")
- When you want to assign a handle to a class name its used as $(".classname")
- When you want to assign a handle to an htmltag its used as $("div")

Lets say i need a thing that is a combination of all these things.
(For that matter it must be a selector that doesnt discriminate one of the above.

for example when i have something like:

```
<input name="whatever" my_custom_trigger="my_identifier">
```

or

```
<div id="thisid" class="thisclass" my_custom_trigger="my_identifier">output</div>
```

I need to assign for example .click to [my_custom_trigger]
since the trigger will be assigned to all types of html items
(div, input, span, or whatever is needed)

So basicly i would have something like

```
$("my_custom_trigger=>my_identifier").click(function(){
    //rest of code
});
```

Is this possible?

@mods: sorry if this is handled before but i find it very difficult to search about this question since i dont know the keywords for finding the same question!

Comment: Have a read through the [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) section of the jQuery docs. You should find what you need in there.

Comment: Yes, you can use HTML5 custom data attributes - http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for such a sintax

```
$("[my_custom_trigger='my_identifier']").first().click(function(){
    //rest of code
});
```

But use data-my_custom_trigger for the attribute name as HTML5 standard expects data- in front of all custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

if its an attribute you could use the [`[attribute='value']`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$("[my_custom_trigger='my_identifier']").click(function(){
    //rest of code
});
```

but that will search on every element in your DOM, wont be that fast to begin with, and its not a valid html markup, if you are using HTML5 you could have it in the `data-attributename` (and change attributename to whatever you want) and bind events that way, but you should make it a bit easier for sizzle to find elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily identify your own selector using:

```
$('*[my_custom_trigger="my_identifier"]').click(function(){
    // do what you wish.
});
```